# ActivityIndicator while takePictureAsync with Expo Camera

Tags: react-native, camera, expo, activity-indicator

I'm developing a React Native app and I want to show an ActivityIndicator component while the Expo Camera is processing the image.

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{alignSelf: 'center'}} onPress={takePicture}>    
  <FontAwesome name="camera" style={{ color: "#FEA428", fontSize: 50, marginBottom: 20}}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

So the function **takePicture** do this:

```
const takePicture = async () => {
  setLoading(prevState => !prevState)
  if(cameraRef){
    let photo = await cameraRef.takePictureAsync({quality: 0.5, skipProcessing: true, fixOrientation: false});
    setLoading(prevState => !prevState)
    setPhotoAbove(photo)

  }
  
}
```

setLoading change the "isLoading" prop which say if the ActivityIndicator is going to be visible or not. However, after the first `setLoading(prevState => !prevState)` then the following code is never executed. Am I missing something here?

EDIT: I'm posting an Expo Snack with the code for testing purposes. In Web the problem isn't visible but for example if you run it on Android it will.

https://snack.expo.io/@avradev/0a8a01

Tks.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your second setLoading just after your await method call like this:

```
const takePicture = async () => {
  setLoading(prevState => !prevState)
  if(cameraRef){
    let photo = await cameraRef.takePictureAsync({quality: 0.5, skipProcessing: true, fixOrientation: false});

    setLoading(prevState => !prevState);

    setPhotoAbove(photo);
  }
 
}
```

Comment: It's a good point but that isn't the problem. Tks anyway. I'm posting a expo snack.